# Is there any way to search for tags in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, tags

I'm currently running the Mozilla Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 desktop email client. In Thunderbird, if I type "linksys router" in the search box, it will find every message in the current folder containing that string.  However, if I tag a message with "xbox 360", a search for "xbox 360" returns nothing.

**Is there an add-on that allows me to search across tags? Would upgrading to the newest Beta version give me this functionality?**

So far I've tried the [GMailUI](http://sites.google.com/site/kmixter/gmailui) add-on and that didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bring up the Search Messages dialog:

> Edit > Find > Search Messages

or

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

[image: run for the tags]

And then change the first drop-down box to **Tags** and search that way.

Answer (score 3):

The `Quick Filter` added in Thunderbird 3.1 also allows to search by tags.

[image: Thunderbird 24.1 Quick Filter]